# How to match an exact path but also a path prefix in the same traefik ingress

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a service that need to receive any request made on

- `/` (exact match)
- `/aaa` (path prefix)

Other paths will be sent to a different service.

Using `traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefix` would work for the the second rule only and `traefik.frontend.rule.type: Path` for the first one only.

What is the recommended way to achieve this? Two distinct ingresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options: As you suggested yourself, you can use two ingress objects. traefik will merge the definitions accordingly.
For the Simple "/" route I assume that you want to do something like a redirect or load a browser client. You can use this annotation

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/aaa/index.html"
```

to redirect from the "/" route to a route that matches your pathprefixstrip.